# JAX RS, I can't see arrays in json output

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, rest, jax-rs

I'm a beginner with JAX RS architecture. I've made a simple class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DatoBase 

    {

      private int _id;
      private String _name;
      private int[] _listId;

//...here all get and set methods
}
```

This class, as you can see has an array (_listId), correctly initialized.
I've made my web services, that correctly istantiate and POST a new element of DatoBase, and I've made a method to GET this element, that is:

```
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("{id}")
    public DatoBase GetDato(@PathParam("id") int dId)
    {
        return dati.get(dId);
    }
```

where dati is declared as:

```
private TreeMap<Integer,DatoBase> dati = new TreeMap<Integer,DatoBase>();
```

but when I try to get the element i've already posted, i see this structure:

```
{"id":"0","name":"Dato10"}
```

I can't see my _listId structure (initialized with 3 elements) in this output.

I expected an output like this:

```
{"id":"0","name":"Dato10","listId":[...]}
```

Could anyone help me or tell me why?
Thank you

Comment: Haven't you annotated your class with javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement? (also look at the formatting of your code)

Comment: yes i've correctly annotated. i just forget to report in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should annotate your array with `@XmlElementWrapper`.

```
@XmlElementWrapper
private int[] _listId;
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html) for further reference.